# Cant connect node.js to mongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I can't connect node.js to mongoDb. I have tried everything I can find: changing the url from localhost to 127.0.0.1, downloading different version on mongo (v6, v5, v4-current one) currently there are no problems with mongo: cmd in the bin file > mongo it shows the databases and collections.

The problem is when I try to run it in VSCode with node.js I run the code shown in the screenshot with node `index.js` the first part of the code is working but I think after `.connect()` something is happening. How to fix this? Also I am new to programing and this is all new for me.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZoUO.png)

I tried the common url fix with mongodb://localhost:27017 and  mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017.

I have tried reinstalling mongo (v4- current, v5, v6) none of the versions work.

```js
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const connectionString = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

const connection = new mongodb.MongoClient(connectionString, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
console.log('connecting next');
connection.connect((err, client) => {
console.log('connected.');
    const db = client.db('testdb');
    const collection = db.collection('collectionTest');
    const query = collection.find({});
    query.toArray((err, data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
})
```

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at [ask], especially the part about including your code: Don't include it as a screenshot, copy the code into the post.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 And you may print out the error message to the console.

Comment: two immediate questions (and please mention me when you answer them): 1) is the mongo server running under localhost:2017? You can check by connecting with the mongo shell to your local server. 2) what happens if you just... wait for a minute? Is there an error? If so, please include that error in your post. And you might want to log that `err` you're getting from the `connect` function to see what's happening. Lastly, have a look into [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) to avoid these callback hells and get a much more intuitive code flow.

Comment: @Plagiatus if i just wait nothing happens the first console.log is printed then no matter how much i wait nothing is happening i tried logging the err after connect() but still nothing happend

Comment: What `mongodb` module version are you using? The couple last versions dont support a callback in `.connect` and return instead a Promise which fulfill when the connection is established. Post your package.json content.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [async / await](https://javascript.info/async-await), like this:

```js
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const connectionString = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

async function connect() {
  const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(connectionString, options);
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db("testdb");
  const collection = db.collection('collectionTest');
  const query = collection.find({});
  const data = await query.toArray();
  console.log(data);
}
```

And yes, your connection string is correct for a local db.